# date extraction from text using regex python

Tags: python, regex

I have a set of strings which contain dates which can be in following format and  I want to extract it using regex in Python

```
5/12/2016  
05/25/15
9/1/2016
05-18-2019
Feb 26,15
Apr 01,2018
Feb18'19
15-Jun-2018
Aug19'17
```

Comment: So, what have you tried so far?

Comment: i can do each of them individually but i dont know  how to join them

Comment: For the numbers, is it MM/DD/YY or DD/MM/YY ?

Comment: Duped: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19994396/best-way-to-identify-and-extract-dates-from-text-python

Comment: you may use [`datefinder`](https://pypi.org/project/datefinder/)

Comment: datefinder is giving way too many dates which are not even there in the text.

Comment: Are these the only formats which you're looking at ? or there are more such formats ?

Comment: No these are the only format that are in the text.

Answer (score 0):

> I can do each of them individually but I don't know how to join them

You can put each of your regular expressions into its own capture group, and "or" them:

```
(regex1)|(regex2)|(regex3)
```

This will match against any string that satisfies at least one of your regular expressions.